# how easy is it to convert java to actionscript to use flash builder?

Tags: java, android, flash, actionscript

i've been making an app for android in java, but i'm curious about convering to actionscript so that i could use flash builder to port my app onto BB and iOS too

is this possible through some sort of automater?

how hard would it be? my app is pretty simplistic in the grand scheme of apps

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert java syntax to actionscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779385/convert-java-syntax-to-actionscript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java and ActionScript 3 are very similar languages (not many people realize this; I certainly didn't at first). Similar in syntax and overarching concepts anyway, although not really in underlying implementations.

The problem for you however is that how Android works is pretty unrelated to how Flash works. Anything tightly bound to the platform is right out the window. Depending on how you designed your system you *may* be able to port over the model and controller components (for example, if you had used an MVC architecture) because they're abstracted away from the platform, but you will need to rebuild the view from scratch.

Heavy emphasis on *may*. Honestly I doubt that would be a good way to proceed; I'm thinking your best bet is simply realize that learning AS3 if you already know Java will be a piece of cake and then redo the entire thing.